# Перевод приложения с WinForms на .NET Core

Tags: winforms, .net-core

Всем привет,
Разработал я приложение на C# с использованием WinForms. Главный функционал приложения это администрирование пользователей ActiveDirectory.

И поступила идея - реализовать все это в браузере.
Почитал я про новые технологии и принял решение - делать на .NET Core. В данный момент сама кросс-платформенность не нужна, сервер будет на винде. Но всякое может случиться, да и технология вроде как классная.
Опыта разработки WEB приложений у меня нет совсем. И у меня как у новичка возникает вопрос - какой UI Framework использовать для отображения пользовательского интерфейса? Красивого интерфейса. С WinForms все было просто, перетащил comboBox или DataGridView и начинай работать, в вебе же все не так просто.
Тысячи разных контролов не нужны, в основном требуются стандартные comboBox, dataGridView, tabControl ну и далее по списку. Некоторые контролы изменены, например для отрисовки кастомных элементов в шапке tabControl, multi-select в comboBox, filtering в dataGridView и т.д.

В общем посоветуйте пожалуйста в сторону чего смотреть.

Answer (score 1):

**Создания сайтов:** В ASP .Net Core не реализованы Web Forms, поэтому штатными средствами создать сайт из готовых примитивов не выйдет. Все участки разметки сайта нужно реализовывать на html самостоятельно.

**Создание программ:** На текущий момент создавать программы с пользовательским интерфейсом можно используя ElectronNET - обертку для Electron, верстая пользовательский интерфейс на html или используя UI-фреймворк Avalonia, программируя пользовательский интерфейс с использованием XAML почти как в WPF. Второе наиболее предпочтительно, на html ничего нормального не наверстаешь с точки зрения десктопных программ

https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET

https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia

На всякий случай сразу оставлю ссылку на шаблон для .Net Core, который создаст графическое приложение с использованием Avalonia https://github.com/tripolskypetr/AvaloniaUiAppTemplate/raw/master/avaloniaui.app.2.0.0.nupkg

Полученный файл устанавливаем командой

```
dotnet new -i avaloniaui.app.2.0.0.nupkg
```

Далее создаем проект из шаблона командой

```
dotnet new avaloniaui
```

Поэтому для красивого интерфейса смотрим на Avalonia, изучить XAML можно в учебном центре Специалист на курсах WPF или Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

При переносе приложения на Asp.Net Core Вам необходимо иметь ввиду, что это будет именно веб-приложение, взаимодействие с которым осуществляется через веб-браузер по протоколу Http, и соответственно Вам сейчас необходимо выбрать стек для клиентской веб разработки. Сама платформа Asp Net Core содержит все средства для генерации веб-представлений ([Руководство по Razor](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)). Также возможен вариант разработки web-api приложения и фронтенда для него на каком либо популярном фронтенд фреймворке (React, Vue, Angular), в случае, если Вам удобнее работать с одностраничными приложениями. Так же Вам рекомендую использовать любой css-фреймворк, например [Bootsrap](https://getbootstrap.com) для внешней стилизации Вашего приложения.

По факту от Вас потребуется разработать веб-представление при помощи технологий, указанных выше, и затем привязать к нему Вашу логику. В случае, если требуется получить приложение для локального запуска, аналогично обычному десктопному приложению, то можно воспользоваться Electron, как посоветовал коллега выше.